# How to figure out the size of the area in a google maps window

Tags: google-maps

I have a Map object created through the google maps api and I want to figure out the distance (km or mi) between the corners of the current view.  I know how to get the coordinates of the corners, is there a utility function to calculate the distance between points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLng

> GLatLng.distanceFrom( other:GLatLng,
>   radius?:Number );
>
> Returns the distance, in meters, from
>   this location to the given location.
>   By default, this distance is
>   calculated given the default
>   equatorial earth radius of 6378137
>   meters. The earth is approximated as a
>   sphere, hence the distance could be
>   off as much as 0.3%, especially in the
>   polar extremes. You may also pass an
>   optional radius argument to calculate
>   distances between GLatLng coordinates
>   on spheres of a different radius than
>   earth.

Answer (score 0):

This somewhat depends on how accurate you need your answer to be.

The Google Maps API includes a function called [distanceFrom](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLng.distanceFrom), which will probably work just fine for you:

> Returns the distance, in meters, from
>   this location to the given location.
>   By default, this distance is
>   calculated given the default
>   equatorial earth radius of 6378137
>   meters. The earth is approximated as a
>   sphere, hence the distance could be
>   off as much as 0.3%, especially in the
>   polar extremes. You may also pass an
>   optional radius  argument to calculate
>   distances between GLatLng coordinates
>   on spheres of a different radius than
>   earth.

If you need a more accurate answer, you will need a function that takes the shape of the Earth into consideration.  I haven't tried it, but [this one](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html) looks great.